# SharePoint list column IF statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

I have run out of IF multiple statement within SharePoint list calculated column, I still have more sites to add.

I'm looking into a different way to build IF statement to fit all my sites (30 in total).

All sites refer to one of this three values: 5, 10, 15.

Trying this formula as an example:

```
IF(AND([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Chester TCC",OR([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Morden" TCC [Speed_limit] = "5mph")), "1", IF(AND([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Liverpool TCC",OR([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Manchester" TCC [Speed_limit] = "10mph")), "1", IF(AND([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Glasgow TCC",OR([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Oxley" TCC [Speed_limit] = "15mph")), "1",, "1", "0")))))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the issue here? Are you getting any error OR is it not showing the expected results?

Comment: Ganesh, formula is giving me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your formula. Try using this instead:

```
=IF(AND([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Chester TCC", OR([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Morden TCC", [Speed_limit] = "5mph")), "1", IF(AND([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Liverpool TCC", OR([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Manchester TCC", [Speed_limit] = "10mph")), "1", IF(AND([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Glasgow TCC", OR([Site_induction] = "UKI- Services- Oxley TCC", [Speed_limit] = "15mph")), "1", "0")))
```

Refer below documentations for syntax of IF, AND, OR, etc. functions:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))
2. [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

Comment: Hi @Jose1978, did you try this formula? does this help you?

Comment: Ganesh, it works perfectly! Thanks a million as always